# Simple C# Windows App - Catch statement always executes no matter what

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, try-catch

Here's the code for the event handler involved:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                seed = Convert.ToInt32(this.Text);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input string is not a sequence of digits.");
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The number cannot fit in an Int32.");
            }

        }
```

It's supposed to ensure a user doesn't type anything but a number allowable by `Int32` into the text box, but the first catch statement executes EVERY time you try to type ANYTHING into the box.  I've looked around but I can't seem to figure out why...

Comment: What is the declaration of `this.Text`?

Comment: is "this.Text" of type TextBox?

Comment: Add `this.Text` to your MessageBox message and you would have found out.

Comment: looks like you want the textbox1.text... not the form's text like your grabbing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because `this.Text` doesn't read from the input box, but rather the class the handler is defined in.

I believe what you want is:

```
try
{
    seed = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)caller).Text);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it tries to Parse the Forms Title.

Comment: There's no "probably" it is.

Comment: Thank you, I specified the name of the TextBox, textBox1, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                seed = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.text);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input string is not a sequence of digits.");
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The number cannot fit in an Int32.");
            }

        }
```

Please use the above statement and it should work correctly. If you type in a number the first exception will not execute.

Comment: Clarifying questions should be posted as comments, not as answers.  If you're going to post an answer it should be phrased declaratively, not as a question.  (In this case this really is an answer, not a clarifying question, so just don't phrase it as a question.)

Comment: In its current form it is an answer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, it is appropriate to be posted as an answer and not a comment, I said that before, but it should, gramatically, be phrased as a declarative statement, not a question, i.e. "Try doing [...]" rather than "Have you tried [...]".

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to see the error message, using the following (temporarily of course):

```
catch (FormatException exception)
{

    MessageBox.Show("Input string is not a sequence of digits."
                    + "Exception message was: " + exception.getMessage());
}
```